# Limit laravel log file size

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I'm new to Laravel, we are using Laravel 5.8, and I have seen horror stories where the log is set to daily rotation, yet still reaches 1gb+ (I saw someone had their log reach over 400gb overnight). Is there a way to split log files up and/limit the amount of total log size that can be created so I don't use up my entire server storage and render it useless.

I have looked all over and didn't find anything that did this other than creating a cron job or something which I am not a fan of in this instance. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/my-laravellog-size-is-31-gb?page=1&replyId=114005

Comment: Thanks @Hossein.Kiani, I already do daily log rotation. The problem is if the daily logs are huge, is it possible to get a maximum file size?

Comment: Did you try this config: log_max_files in the config/app.php file?

Comment: This will limit the amount of days back the log will show, not log size.

Comment: try this https://www.milevis.com/tips/details/keep-limited-log-file-size-in-php-laravel

Comment: Maybe out of scope, but what are you logging? 1Gb sounds like a lot. If it are errors, please fix them. If it are trace logs, there are other ways. Log files are clumsy. Just a flat text file. My log files on a 40K+ page requests website generates a max of 1kb a day.

Answer (score 8):

In Linux, there is a concept named `logrotate`, which can manage any log file based on date or size.
I think in Laravel for managing log files based on size, the `logrotate` is an acceptable choice.
for more info:
[Link1](https://docs.rackspace.com/support/how-to/understanding-logrotate-utility/)
[Link2](https://betterstack.com/community/guides/logging/linux/how-to-manage-log-files-with-logrotate-on-ubuntu-20-04)

sample:

1. create a file for your application on:
   `sudo touch /etc/logrotate.d/yourappname`
2. the content of `yourappname` file would be something like:

```
   

<your-project-directory-absolute-path>/storage/logs/*.log {
        size 10k
        missingok
        rotate 7
        compress
        notifempty
        create 0644  www-data  www-data
        su www-data www-data
   }
```

Comment: This is best server related storage issue.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by a custom log middleware which checks for file size and do changes accordingly.

I found this on internet, you can reference it.

https://gist.github.com/catzie/5511fb4ba0d0e386fd7d77209c9f004f

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware

Answer (score -1):

You try this

```
$filePath = storage_path() . '/logs/laravel.log'; 
$bakFilePath = storage_path() . '/logs/laravel.log.bak';
$maxFileSize = 11000000;
$shrinkedFileSize = 10000000;
 
$success = shrinkFile($filePath, $bakFilePath, $maxFileSize, $shrinkedFileSize);
```

also follow this [url](https://www.milevis.com/tips/details/keep-limited-log-file-size-in-php-laravel) for more help

Ok, it's now possible this file is deleted automaticaly . You just need to update laravel, and add this in your config/app.php file:

```
'log_max_files' => 30
```

On Laravel  You can find config/logging.php file:

```
'daily' => [
    'driver' => 'daily',
    'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
    'level' => 'debug',
    'days' => 30, // 0 for unilimitted logs
],
```

set the number of days logfile removed automaicaly .